# JPL7, list of strings in prolog-query

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

i have a prolog-query which needs an array as atom:

searchEventsOnCategory(Categories,Events)
Categories is a list of strings.

Example input:
searchEventsOnCategory(['Bar','Disco'],Events)

Output:
Event = [listOfEvents]

```
searchEventsOnCategory(Categories,Events):-
    findall([X,V], event(X,_,_,V), List),
    compareCategories(List,Categories,Events1),
    Events = Events1.
```

My java-code is:

```
public ArrayList<String> getEventsByPrologWithCategories(ArrayList<String> Categories){
    ArrayList<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();

    //(Persons,Budget,Categories,Events)
    Variable X = new Variable("X");
    Compound V = new Compound("[Bar]");

    Query q4 =
            new Query(
                "searchEventsOnCategory",
                new Term[] {V,X}
            );

    ... 

    return events;

}
```

How i have to devine V, that prolog get the V as a list of Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Compound, you should use Term

```
Variable X = new Variable("X");

Term t = Util.textToTerm("[Bar]");

Query q4 =
    new Query(
        "searchEventsOnCategory",
        new Term[] {t,X}
        );
```